# Locate redirect in production script

Tags: php, redirect

I have inherited working on a very large php website. We're running into some issues where certain pages are causing strange redirects. I'm looking for some ideas to help find these redirects in the php code.

We are not hosting the site so we do not have shell access. Originally I was going to hook into a shutdown function or a destructor and log the call stack, but the call stack looks to only contain the exit function. Next I was looking for ways to override the php 'header' function (through namespaces most likely) but this would involve adding the namespace to too many files.

Are there any php techniques, short of placing die statements everywhere or downloading all of the source code and running grep over it, that would allow finding which redirect in the code is being triggered?

Comment: Can you look at the server logs and look for 301/302s?

Comment: Attach a debugger and/or profiler.

Comment: Live bug fixing a production site is not good, no VCS to look at the code? Risky!

Comment: @fubar - the logs seem to show the requested URI and the redirect URI - can they be adjusted to capture the file and line where the redirect occurred?

Comment: @Sammitch - I have tried to pull the production site local and attach a debugger, (I'm still attempting actually) they have around 5 paid modules linked to an active domain, these modules do not run from anywhere else and the site requires them to run, removing them breaks many other parts of the site.

Comment: @JonFreynik I don't think so. But whether you can efficiently map a request URL to a file in your website, I do not know.

Comment: i was able to solve this today and i believe i have a general purpose function that can help with finding redirects as well as possibly other items in code, i will post as soon as i have time to write it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Avoid debugging on a live production site whenever possible. If you must, then I would set up "gates" to prevent other people from seeing your tests. You can do this by checking for an IP address or a custom GET variable. The following are two PHP examples.

```
if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") {
    // Run Your Code Here
}
```

or

```
if (!empty($_GET["my_custom_get_var"])) {
    // Run Your Code Here
}
```

**Technique 1 - PHP Specific**

Sometimes the easiest way to find something or test if something is working is to try to break it. In this case, for a PHP redirect to be successful (which uses the PHP `header` function), it requires that no header information was sent to the browser before making the call. So first, see if you can trigger the dreaded `headers already sent` warning by outputting anything ahead of that call. If you can trigger that warning you should be able to get the line number and file of where the redirect is occurring. From there you can `debug_backtrace()` to find the culprit of the redirect.

If output buffering is on, you will want to disable that temporarily or flush it for your test.

**Technique 2 - WordPress Specific**

I thought I would also throw in a WordPress solution in case you are working on a very large WordPress site. As long as the code / plug-in that is causing the redirect is using WordPress's core then you should be able to tap into their hook system. The following would be a test you could run from the "functions.php" file in the active template / theme - which should show you the stack trace leading up to the redirect.

```
function my_custom_function ($location, $status) {
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
    exit;
}
add_filter("wp_redirect", "my_custom_function" , 10, 2);
```